# How to get all days inside a week?

Tags: r, lubridate, week-number

I have a period that I want to divide into weeks from Monday to Sunday.

Using `lubridate`, I can query the week number of a date:

```
library(lubridate)
td = today()
week(td) #48
```

How could I find all the days that belong to the 48th week of, say, 2020?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `seq` and `as.Date`, where `%Y` is the year, `%W` Week of the year and `%a` Abbreviated weekday.

```
seq(as.Date("2020-48-Mo", "%Y-%W-%a"), by=1, length.out=7)
#as.Date("2020-48-Mo", "%Y-%W-%a") + 0:6 #Alternative
#as.Date("2020-48-1", "%Y-%W-%u") + 0:6 #Alternative
#[1] "2020-11-30" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-02" "2020-12-03" "2020-12-04"
#[6] "2020-12-05" "2020-12-06"
```

Use `%U` in case Sunday is the first day and `%W` with Monday and having the weeks starting with `0`. Use `%V` with Monday as the first day and weeks starting with `1`.

In case you have a Date and want all days of this week:

```
x <- as.Date("2020-11-25")
x - as.integer(format(x, "%u")) + 1:7
#[1] "2020-11-23" "2020-11-24" "2020-11-25" "2020-11-26" "2020-11-27"
#[6] "2020-11-28" "2020-11-29"
```

Comment: Nice! I'd never used `%U`.

Comment: Almost, but that doesn't quite do it: the OP wanted all dates in e.g. week 48.   `seq(as.Date("2020-48", "%Y-%U"), by=1, length.out=7) %>% week()` gives: `[1] 48 48 49 49 49 49 49`

Comment: I think R and lubridate count differently, R counts only full weeks from the start of the year and lubridate uses actual calendar years. For example is this week in R the 48th full week starting from a Monday, even though it is the 49th calendar week, because the week started in 2019.

Comment: I get with `format(seq(as.Date("2020-48-Mo", "%Y-%W-%a"), by=1, length.out=7), "%W")` `"48" "48" "48" "48" "48" "48" "48"`. Also it depends if you start counting the weeks from `0` or from `1`.

Comment: Great, this is very clever! Note that `lubridate::parse_date()` does not support those very handy formats.

Answer (score 1):

Based on GKi's answer, I could write a quite handy function:

```r
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts=F)
library(glue, warn.conflicts=F)
get_week = function(x){
  week_monday = glue("{year(x)}-{isoweek(x)-1}-1")
  week_monday = as.Date(week_monday, "%Y-%W-%u")
  seq(week_monday, by=1, length.out=7)
}
get_week(ymd("2020-11-25")) #a wednesday
#> [1] "2020-11-23" "2020-11-24" "2020-11-25" "2020-11-26" "2020-11-27"
#> [6] "2020-11-28" "2020-11-29"
get_week(ymd("2020-11-30")) #a monday
#> [1] "2020-11-30" "2020-12-01" "2020-12-02" "2020-12-03" "2020-12-04"
#> [6] "2020-12-05" "2020-12-06"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Instead of getting the monday-string you can use `%u` and `1`

Comment: @GKi very true, I corrected my function, thanks again!

Comment: An alternative can be: `get_week <- function(x) {seq(x - as.integer(format(x, "%u")) + 1, by=1, length.out=7)}`